# Should i manully defer context cancellation with grpc calls?

Tags: go, grpc

Im trying to understand if a context could potentially cause a memory leak.

```golang
    md := metadata.Pairs("id", uuid.New().String(), "user", "test_user")
    grpcContext := metadata.NewOutgoingContext(context.Background(), md)
    resp, err := grpcClient.PutRecord(grpcContext, req)
```

Im creating a context with metadata from background context. Can someone help me understand if gRPC library would cancel the context or should I defer a context cancellation.

If i understand correctly, it doesnt depend on the GRPC implementation since this method is generated from a protobuf. (Please correct me if im missing something here)

Comment: No cancel function is returned by either `context.Background` and `metadata.NewOutgoingContext` so there is nothing to cancel.

Comment: Yeah i agree, but im wondering how does the context gets closed? I can create  a context with cancel function. Does the gRPC call close the context?

Comment: If you create a cancel function you are responsible to call it yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by "close" the context? If you create a context with cancelation, then yes, the cancel function must be called. There is no other way to cancel it. To quote the docs: _"Failing to call the `CancelFunc` leaks the child and its children until the parent is canceled or the timer fires. The `go vet` tool checks that `CancelFuncs` are used on all control-flow paths."_

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://pkg.go.dev/context#Background) out. Let's understand a few things about context:

- every application has one high level context.
- context.Background() always returns this high level context.
- The background context is alive for the span of the application (never gets canceled).
- Contexts are thread safe

Since contexts are thread safe, the same background context can be accessed in each process serving a request. However, its only recommended to be used by the main function, initialization, and tests. For each request, a context is derived from a higher level context (parent context). By default, it will be the background context (highest context in hierarchy).

From go docs:

`Calling the CancelFunc cancels the child and its children, removes the parent's reference to the child, and stops any associated timers. Failing to call the CancelFunc leaks the child and its children until the parent is "canceled" or the "timer fires"`

following are ways to create a context:

1. WithDeadline
2. WithTimeOut
3. WithCancel
4. WithValue

1 and 2 are sure to have their Done channel closed canceled when the timer fires. For 3, you have to be extra cautious and ensure that the context is cancelled (unless, it's parent context is sure to get closed at some point). 4 is considered for request scope only.

deferring a cancel call is the best way to ensure closure. And like @JimB pointed out, `goVet` checks and ensures Cancel is called to avoid leaks.